# Microsoft Graph API - Upload new document version without loosing metadat

Tags: c#, upload, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We're using Microsoft Graph API to upload documents to SharePoint Document Library, this documents have some metadata asssociated as document library columns such as "DocStatus" , "DocType" , "DocFormat"….

We want to upload a new version of a document to SP using GraphAPI, overwriting it, and we don't want to lose the metadata previously associated to it, also, we don't want to increase two versions to guarantee that the previous version metadata is persisted.

Example - Upload new version file using Graph API

- Step 1

  - User uploads document for the first time and updates it's metadata:
  - Two versions of the document are created :

    - One version for the uploaded file
    - Second version for metadata asssignment

    Upload document:

```
              upload = await _graphServiceClient
                  .Sites[siteId]
                  .Drives[driveId]
                  .Root
                  .ItemWithPath(uploadFileName)
                  .Content
                  .Request()
                  .PutAsync<DriveItem>(file);
```

- Step 2
- User uploads a new file through the SPA page, a new version is created (V3), however the document metadata is overwritten:

Update document version:

```
                     await _graphServiceClient
                          .Sites[siteId]
                          .Drives[driveId]
                          .Items[itemId]
                          .ListItem
                          .DriveItem
                          .Content
                          .Request()
                          .PutAsync<DriveItem>(file);
```

[Example of metadata overwritten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghxh1.png)

We also know that in the case of docx documents, this metadata is persisted as document properties in the docx itself, but we can't guarantee that the new file being uploaded will be the exactly same file that was downloaded, so , is there a way that we can associate metadata to a document and upload it all at the same time (document and metadata) within the same version?

Or a way that we can overwrite the file , and not the metadata?

**Note:**

The final user will not use Sharepoint Online to manipulate documents. They will use a SPA page totally independent from Sharepoint. This SPA consumes .NET API's that are implemented with Microsoft Graph API.